# Why do UVICORN/Starlette/FastAPI spawn more threads when not using "ASYNC" and don't when using "ASYNC"?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, uvicorn, starlette

Okay, so I was working on a comparison study on `using ASYNC vs without using ASYNC in FastAPI`. However, I have arrived at some unexpected results, and don't understand why.

## Here is the setup 1:

### THE API WHICH DOES NOT USE ASYNC

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
import PIL.Image as Image
import requests
from loguru import logger
import sys

log_format = "{level} {process}-{thread} {time} {name}:{line} - {message}"
logger.remove()
logger.add(sys.stderr, format=log_format, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)
logger.add("logs/" + "t_{time}.log", format=log_format, colorize=True, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

def get_the_image_from_net():
    a = requests.get("https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x21600x21600.A1.jpg")
    return True


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/expectoPatronum")
def get_image_of_the_new_world():
    """
    Gets Image of the World
    """
    logger.info("Received request for getting Image of the world")
    image_bytes: bytes = get_the_image_from_net()
    logger.info("Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array")
    return True

uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=10009)
```

### How I am calling ABOVE API (by using Multiprocessing Pool)

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import requests


def test_function(index_iterator: int):
    start_time = time.time()
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:10009/expectoPatronum")
    print(f"response.content: {str(response.content)}")
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("----------------------NOT 200")
        print(f"response.content: {str(response.content)}")
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time


pool = Pool(5)
pool.map(test_function, [i for i in range(1,6)])
pool.close
```

and this is what the LOGS read from my API's end when they are called:

```py
INFO 9408-140671786272512 2022-07-13T01:32:37.498465+0530 __main__:27 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9408-140671777879808 2022-07-13T01:32:37.501623+0530 __main__:27 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9408-140671769487104 2022-07-13T01:32:37.504744+0530 __main__:27 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9408-140671760897792 2022-07-13T01:32:37.504929+0530 __main__:27 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9408-140671752242944 2022-07-13T01:32:37.505638+0530 __main__:27 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9408-140671786272512 2022-07-13T01:33:04.845982+0530 __main__:29 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9408-140671777879808 2022-07-13T01:33:16.167435+0530 __main__:29 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9408-140671769487104 2022-07-13T01:33:17.284000+0530 __main__:29 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9408-140671752242944 2022-07-13T01:33:37.771086+0530 __main__:29 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9408-140671760897792 2022-07-13T01:33:38.016435+0530 __main__:29 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
```

### Please note: there are multiple threads created (140671786272512, 140671777879808 ..and so on)

## Here is the setup 2:

### THE API WHICH USES ASYNC

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, APIRouter
import httpx
from loguru import logger
import sys

log_format = "{level} {process}-{thread} {time} {name}:{line} - {message}"
logger.remove()
logger.add(sys.stderr, format=log_format, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)
logger.add("logs/" + "t_{time}.log", format=log_format, colorize=True, backtrace=True, diagnose=True)

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

async def get_the_image_from_net():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        a = await client.get('https://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73751/world.topo.bathy.200407.3x21600x21600.A1.jpg')

    return True


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/expectoPatronum")
async def get_image_of_the_new_world():
    """
    Gets Image of the World
    """
    logger.info("Received request for getting Image of the world")
    image_bytes = await get_the_image_from_net()
    logger.info("Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array")
    return True

uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=10008)
```

### How I am calling ABOVE API (by using Multiprocessing Pool (same as above calling method, different PORT number though)

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import requests


def test_function(index_iterator: int):
    start_time = time.time()
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:10008/expectoPatronum")
    print(f"response.content: {str(response.content)}")
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("----------------------NOT 200")
        print(f"response.content: {str(response.content)}")
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time


pool = Pool(5)
pool.map(test_function, [i for i in range(1,6)])
pool.close
```

and this is what the LOGS read from my API's end when they are called:

```py
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:36:26.762525+0530 __main__:43 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:36:26.776561+0530 __main__:43 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:36:26.783669+0530 __main__:43 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:36:26.790367+0530 __main__:43 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:36:26.796934+0530 __main__:43 - Received request for getting Image of the world
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:37:38.086156+0530 __main__:45 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:37:43.709798+0530 __main__:45 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:37:43.827959+0530 __main__:45 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:37:47.218717+0530 __main__:45 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
INFO 9442-140295303571264 2022-07-13T01:37:51.712889+0530 __main__:45 - Image has been downloaded and processed as bytes array
```

### Please note: there is only 1 thread (140295303571264)

Now I am unable to figure out:
Why in SETUP-1, uvicorn spawns more than 1 thread? I thought it is a single-threaded Server and how can I restrict it to spawn only 1 thread inside the process?

The time-results from both setups are really discouraging.
For SETUP-1 which does not use async, times are: `27.36284899711609,38.68544268608093,39.79848337173462,60.28416633605957,60.529775857925415`

For SETUP-2 which uses async, times are: `71.32960891723633,76.95274710655212,77.07157778739929,80.4650149345398,84.95978450775146`

Comment: FastAPI uses a threadpool of 40 threads internally to handle requests using non-async endpoints. When using async, only a single thread is used (since a thread not awaiting should be occupied with CPU bound stuff). You can usually tell your ASGI server to run multiple workers instead.

Comment: Yup, "adding" `async` to my non-async API made it single-threaded like I wanted it to be.

Comment: @MatsLindh can you link to a source about the number of threads (40) you've mentioned?

Comment: @VictorBouhnik https://anyio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/threads.html#adjusting-the-default-maximum-worker-thread-count "The default AnyIO worker thread limiter has a value of 40, meaning that any calls to `to_thread.run_sync()` without an explicit limiter argument will cause a maximum of 40 threads to be spawned."

Comment: @VictorBouhnik Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 5):

When you declare a path operation function with normal `def` instead of `async def`, it is run in an external `threadpool` that is then awaited, instead of being called directly (as it would block the server). You can read more  [in FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#async-and-await)